# ¿Que quiere decir "crocodila"?

Tags: definiciones, adjetivos, palabras-raras

En "León prodigioso" de Gómez de Tejada encuentro esta frase:

> A un lado entre espesos jarales descubrieron una cruel hiena, de aquella crocodila hermosura y aleves lágrimas, alcahueta falsa, que halagüeña y cariciosa ....

No aparece en el DLE; lo más parecido es [crocodilo](https://dle.rae.es/crocodilo) como variante poco usada de cocodrilo. Sin embargo, no creo que exista relación, dado que:

- Crocodilo es un sustantivo, mientras que *crocodila hermosura* indica que *crocodila* es un adjetivo, y
- En el texto se aplica a una hiena

Comment: Se me ocurre que sea una licencia poética. Lo relacionaría con "lágrimas de cocodrilo", como indicando que su hermosura no es verdadera y en línea con la hipocresía que se le atribuye en toda la oración.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que estamos ante un fenómeno lingüístico conocido como **metábasis**.

De acuerdo con el [Diccionario Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/metabasis)

> **metábasis**
> Lingüística
> El plural es metábasis
>  1 Fenómeno por el cual una
> palabra que corresponde a una determinada categoría pasa a desempeñar
> una función que corresponde a otra categoría.

Más concretamente, cuando un nombre pasa a desempeñar la función de un adjetivo, tenemos la acción de **adjetivar**, que según [el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/adjetivar?m=form) es

> **adjetivar**
> 2. tr. Gram. Convertir en adjetivo una palabra o un grupo de palabras. U. m. c. prnl. El sustantivo hombre se adjetiva en *Es muy hombre*.

Otro ejemplo mucho más usado de este recurso lo tenemos en la duodécima acepción de [**perro**](https://dle.rae.es/perro)

> 1. m. y f. Mamífero doméstico de la familia de los cánidos, de tamaño, forma y pelaje muy diversos, según las razas, que tiene olfato muy
>    fino y es inteligente y muy leal a su dueño. U. en m. ref. a la
>    especie.
>
> ...
>
> 12. adj. coloq. Dicho de una cosa: Muy mala o indigna. **Vida perra**.

En tu caso el nombre **cocodrilo** en su forma arcaica **crocodilo** pasa a convertirse en adjetivo adquiriendo el género femenino de la palabra a que acompaña.

> de aquella **crocodila** hermosura

Es decir una hermosura similar a la que tiene un cocodrilo, supongo. Hermosura bastante escasa en mi opinión y supongo que en la del autor.

Comment: Interesante y plausible - gracias

Comment: @Joseph_Jaroslav :S Sí, un pequeño lapsus. Corregido. Gracias!